# Trying to create a Counter in my Xamarin app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm currently making an Android App with Xamarin in Visual Studio for Mac and need a page counter in the top-right corner of every page. The way the app is structured is this:

- *Title page:* Person enters name and chooses one of two options
- *Second page:* Question and two options/buttons to choose from
- *Third page:* Same idea as the second…

I want the counter to be included at the top of each page, starting with the title page, and increment with the touch of each option/button. I was thinking of implementing some code in the class specific to each button.

Here's what I've got for one of the buttons on the third page (called `yesResponse`) that would go to a "new" second page (`statusPage`):

```cs
private void OnLEFTButtonClicked(object navigationSend, EventArgs e)
{
  var statusPage = new StatusPage(navigationSend);
  Navigation.PushModalAsync(statusPage);
  pageValue++;
  pageCount.Text = pageValue.ToString("2");
  var storeData = Path.Combine(App.FolderPath, $"{Path.GetRandomFileName()}.trial.txt"); // to save responses/data
}
```

Comment: So you'd like your counter to measure the total number of options the user has selected across all pages, correct? Must the user select one option on each page? Are the options always exclusive, such that they can _only_ select on option? Or is it possible for them to select multiple options on some pages?

Comment: That's basically the idea yes (in response to your first question). And it is one option per page.

Comment: What is your actual question?  You've told us your requirements and showed us some code - is there a question to go with it?  What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: @Jason: My read of this is that the OP is trying to figure out how to maintain state for the counter across multiple pages, and how to increment that state each time the user selects an option.

Comment: @AnonymissAn You want to count the pages in Navigation stack? Or you want to pass value between two pages, you have some problems?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT yes I want to pass a value between two pages that increments by 1 each time

Comment: @Anonymiss About Passing data between twp page, you can use the constructor. Because I am not sure what you want to do, please take a look this thread firstly:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353374/xamarin-pass-data-to-another-page