# How do I access and change properties of a control that is in a different Window in a multi-windows MAUI app?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

Two years back I designed a game Scoreboard application for windows. It was a multi-window application(2 windows to be exact) where one window contained the controls for increasing or reducing the scores of a game and the other window was the actual scoreboard that displayed the scores. The Scoreboard window would be displayed to the public using a projector( windows extended desktop) and the other window would be on the laptop screen and operated by the scorer.

using WPF controls, XAML and C# it was straightforward to code.

In the main windows code file I declared an instance of the second window

```
public scoreboard1 sboard = new scoreboard1();
```

in that, I coded a click event on the main window to change the text property in the other window
by using the simple line of code below.

```
sboard.txtBlckScoreBoardHTPoints.Text = "btn clicked on main window";
```

How do I simply do the same in MAUI?

I tried to follow similar tutorials (like those in the link below) on multi-window support in MAUI applications. They only refer to just creating and opening another window.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/windows?view=net-maui-7.0

I need an example of how to access and manipulate the controls of the window from another window in the MAUI paradigm

Am currently using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.5.3

I have tried the following in MAUI

So far in the click event of a button

```
var pjScreen = new Window(new screen2());
```

to open the window I used the line of code below.

```
Application.Current.OpenWindow(pjScreen);
```

Comment: you need to learn how to use MVVM and data binding.  Directly manipulating the UI elements of another page or window is generally a very bad idea

Comment: The application was designed to be used on desktop environment not mobile, but i was thinking of porting it to MAUI as a way of learning MAUI and to utilize what MAUI has to offer.

Comment: That’s irrelevant, having different views directly manipulating each other is really poor design

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you should think clearly about interface design. On mobile, the interface is not large, if you put two windows on two pages, then the two windows generally do not appear on one page at the same time.

Depending on the interface design, the implementation method is also different.

If the two windows on the same page, you can use [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm?view=net-maui-7.0) to achieve this.

You can refer to the following code:

1.create a view model `MyViewModel.cs`

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        private int _result;
        public int Result 
        {
            get => _result;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _result, value);
            }
        }

        public ICommand IncreaseCommand => new Command(() => {

            Result++;
        });

        public ICommand DecreaseCommand => new Command(() => {

            Result--;
        });

        public MyViewModel() {
            Result = 0;
        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

2.usage example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp328"
             x:Class="MauiApp328.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MyViewModel></local:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Start">

            <Label
                x:Name="sBoard"
                Text="{Binding Result}"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <HorizontalStackLayout  
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                >
                <Button Text="+" WidthRequest="80" Command="{Binding IncreaseCommand}"></Button>

                <Button Text="-"  WidthRequest="80" Command="{Binding DecreaseCommand}" Margin="10,0,10,0"></Button>

            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

If the two windows on two different pages, you can pass data between the two pages.

For how to pass data between the two pages, you can check case: [Pass data back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74561572/pass-data-back-from-maui-shell-navigation/74567945#74567945) or [pass parameters using constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353374/xamarin-pass-data-to-another-page).

Comment: FYI The OP is not talking about a mobile application

Comment: It seems like i better stick with wpf for that particular project, because the suggestion seem a little complex and would require me to develop the application from the group up.

Comment: @Deo You should use ViewModels for MAUI or WPF - so there is no difference of being "complex"

Comment: Hi @Deo, it is not complex at all, you can just use binding and MVVM to achieve this, just referring to my code above.